# Was Jedi robe a uniform during the clone wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In a discussion I had about the possibility Jedi commiting war crimes on the grounds of being non-uniformed combatants with concealed weapon. Someone pointed out that a Jedi Robe is visibly distinguishes them from others. And the question I wanted to ask here is - does it? Because I think it's only distinct on-screen for the benefit of the viewer. Some pointers:

- Jedi wearing a clone trooper armour is obviously totally fine. It distinguishes them as the members of the republic force quite clearly.
- Episode IV indirectly implies that a robe is a normal clothing for people to wear (Obi-Wan doesn't raise suspicion).
- In Episode I Qui-Gonn Jinn tries to swindle a Toydorian out of his stock using a mind-control technique. When it fails, the Toydorian specifically says something in the color of "who do you think you are, a jedi?" not realising one actually stands before him. (Though maybe Jedi are unexpected to be seen on the planet, to the point that even looking at one doesn't cross anyone's mind).
- There are scenes in Episode II on Coruscant where robed jedi walk in the crowd or a bar without raising suspicion. (Though maybe people are used to them. Even in a bar. Even offering Jedi some DeathSticks.)
- In Episode II there's like a hundred Jedi on an arena who covertly got there despite wearing an outfit. (though honestly they should be noticed just because they're not native Geonosians, so maybe it's just a movie flub).
- There are some scenes from Episode II I faintly recall but couldn't find them, they may have been removed during some edition alterations:

1. A crash-landing on the street of coruscant where Anakin tells people it's a "Jedi Business" without showing lightsaber or anything and they just all scatter, which would mean they have instantly recognised him as a Jedi (or he used a mindtrick);
2. A scene at said bar where Obi-Wan tells Anakin to split up to avoid suspicion (meaning their robes aren't instantly recognisable);

- Legends are welcome. I'm looking for an answer that would make sense in-universe.

Please note that I'm not asking if there was a rule that forced Jedi to wear a specific type of attire - I'm asking if the attire they adopted distinguishes them from the general population in a military situation in a way that would increase the likelyhood of their adversaries confusing enemy jedi with a neutral person who happened to be in a warzone.

Comment: Addressed in [my answer to the dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115250/20774) - *"**The tunic, robes and cloaks worn by Jedi are honored traditions, but not uniforms**. From the time they become Padawans, Jedi are free to dress as they choose"*

Comment: As with the possession of a lightsaber, looking like a Jedi (in robes) and saying *"Jedi business"* in a confident voice is probably sufficient to assuage their interest of passers-by

Comment: I'm not asking if they're described as uniforms in-universe, but if they function as one - i. e. does someone wearing one get instantly recognise as such in the context of the clone wars.

Comment: That's a very broad question. Out on planets like Tatooine, people wear robes all the time and a Jedi robe wouldn't be noticeable. On Coruscant, most people seem to dress in a 'futuristic' style so a Jedi robe stands out a mile.

Comment: Yep! Which is why I'm specifically asking about a military situation in the clone wars, if it's likely to confuse an enemy jedi with an innocent bystander who happens to dress similarly. The point is to assess if it's not a stretch to assume that they're commiting a war crime. Simple yes or no question. If it is the case, then there's just one good example needed.